# Remote SSH - save/upload progress

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using this "Remote SSH" extension to open and edit remote files directly, and it's working fine in general except when you try to save a file there is no progress output at all for me to tell if the file has been saved or not. There is nothing in the "Output" or "Debug Console" tabs. Does anyone know how I can see the progress of file saving/uploading at all?

Comment: There is no uploading, you're editing/saving on the remote machine directly. You can check when the file was last saved in the terminal I guess. What kind of files are you saving in VSCode that you'd need a progress bar?